# iOS: How to control sound volume (not ringer) when user presses button?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have some speech in my app.
The iPhones buttons only affect the volume while the phone is speaking. As soon as the sentence finishes, the buttons affect the 'ringer' volume.

But I would like for the buttons to always affect 'volume' when my app is open. How can I achieve this?